# Turn an image's onError function into a return

Tags: javascript, onload, onerror

So I need a function to test if an image can load or not. Here's what I've got:

```
function imgExists(url){
    var img = new Image();
    img.onerror = function(){
        alert('error')
    }
    img.onload = function (){
    alert('load')
    }
    img.src = url;
}

imgExists('http://hashtraffic.com/img/jackson@2x.png')
```

The issue is that the alerts are trapped in their won functions. How can I get the `imgExists()` function to return true if the image loads and false if it does not?

Comment: The image will load asynchronously, so you cannot return a value immediately from the function. You will have to follow the deferred execution pattern and either provide a callback for your function to call, or have it return a Deferred object.

Comment: Any examples? How do I provide a callback?

Comment: You pass it as parameter to your function and call it inside the function when you have the result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use a callback, since your function is inherently asynchronous:

```
function imgExists(url, callback) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onerror = function() {
        callback(false);
    }
    img.onload = function () {
        callback(true);
    }
    img.src = url;
}

function checkImage(exists) {
    alert("Image exists: " + exists); // Usage example.
}

imgExists('http://hashtraffic.com/img/jackson@2x.png', checkImage);
```

Comment: But that's an alert, not a return.

Comment: @JacksonGariety: `// Usage example.`! The code that needs the result goes into the callback. Instead of an `alert`, do whatever you want to do, e.g. test whether `exists` is `true` or `false` and act accordingly. That's how callbacks work.

Comment: So in the rest of my code, I have `if (imgExists('http://...') == true) { //etc }` how can I modify that to check the callback?

Comment: @JacksonGariety: `if (exists) { //etc }` goes into the callback.

Comment: Thanks! Will check in 5 mins.

Comment: Very long five minutes